# What is a correct overpass-turbo query for “turn:lane=*”,

Tags: overpass-api, overpass-turbo

Tried using the below query. But the result was an empty dataset. Please let me know whether the query I'm using is correct or not

```
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “"turn:lane"=*”
  node["turn:lane=*"]({{bbox}});
  way["turn:lane=*"]({{bbox}});
  relation["turn:lane=*"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Comment: Maybe this combination isn't used in your AOI?

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't seem right, as it would be looking for a key named `turn:lane=*`. Obviously, neither "=" nor "*" are part of the key, so your query won't return anything.

Another issue is, that the tag is called turn:lanes, rather than turn:lane. Right now, there's exactly one single way using this incorrect spelling: https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/turn%3Alane

Corrected query:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “"turn:lanes"=*”
  node["turn:lanes"]({{bbox}});
  way["turn:lanes"]({{bbox}});
  relation["turn:lanes"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

To avoid this overly verbose syntax, you can as well write:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
nwr["turn:lanes"]({{bbox}});
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Comment: Yes initially, I used the same query but didnt work out than used the key "turn:lane=*". I want the result for turnlanes whether it may be right or left so used * in the key phrase.

Comment: Can you please update your question and state exactly which tags you need in your result?

Comment: We want to detection Turn lane markings on the Satellite image. In a document it stated that we can use these tags  “turn:lane=*”, “turn:lane:forward=*”, “turn:lane:backward=*” to fetch the results.